# Getting slices of a dataframe using a column of index tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` where the indices increase monotonically, but are not consecutive numbers:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.random(10), 'col2': np.random.random(10)}, index=sorted(np.random.choice(np.arange(30), size=10, replace=False)))
>>  df 
        col1      col2
0   0.056598  0.405284
3   0.743229  0.824497
5   0.718957  0.350812
10  0.880591  0.807667
16  0.431084  0.152207
17  0.695128  0.688832
20  0.678114  0.330415
23  0.718925  0.721982
25  0.315871  0.904885
29  0.198524  0.047869
```

I have another dataframe that contains start-end tuples, and the aim is to get the mean of the slice corresponding to each:

```
>> idx_df = pd.DataFrame({'idxs': [(0, 3), (2, 6), (3, 5), (6, 10)]})
>> idx_df
      idxs
0   (0, 3)
1   (2, 6)
2   (3, 5)
3  (6, 10)
```

So what I want is a dataframe containing the means:

```
>> target_df
   col1                        col2
0  df.loc[0:3, 'col1'].mean()  df.loc[0:3, 'col2'].mean()
1  df.loc[2:6, 'col1'].mean()  df.loc[2:6, 'col2'].mean()
2  df.loc[3:5, 'col1'].mean()  df.loc[3:5, 'col2'].mean()
3  df.loc[6:10, 'col1'].mean() df.loc[6:10, 'col2'].mean()
```

What I currently have is an `apply` function:

```
idx_df.apply(lambda row: df.loc[row['idxs'][0]:row['idxs'][1], ['col1', 'col2']].mean(axis=0), axis=1)
```

but for my actual dataframe, this is really slow. I presume this is because `apply` is essentially a for loop. Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
#convert the tuples in the idx_df into a DF with a columns of start and end
df2=(pd.DataFrame(idx_df['idxs'].tolist(), 
                  index=idx_df.index)
       .rename(columns={0:'start', 1:'end'}))

# we need to group all the rows in DF that fall within the start-end range
# which means some rows will be duplicated 
# so, we do a cross join to combine the two DF
df3=df.reset_index().merge(df2, how='cross')

# cross join has m by n rows, we choose the ones 
# where DF index falls within start and end
# then a groupby and take mean for the two columns
df3=df.reset_index().merge(df2, how='cross')
(df3.loc[(df3['index']>=df3['start']) &
        (df3['index']<=df3['end']  )]
    .groupby(['start','end'], as_index=False)[['col1','col2']].mean()
    .drop(columns=['start','end'])
)
```

```
        col1        col2
0   0.857828    0.528455
1   0.704038    0.638850
2   0.481587    0.889652
3   0.406341    0.146850
```

data used

```
DF

col1    col2
0   0.789167    0.668862
2   0.926490    0.388049
5   0.481587    0.889652
10  0.406341    0.146850
11  0.769739    0.074072
17  0.578132    0.494691
19  0.294506    0.893230
21  0.599694    0.437029
22  0.678959    0.463787
29  0.107473    0.108720

idxs
0   (0, 3)
1   (2, 6)
2   (3, 5)
3   (6, 10)
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that if I have several items in idx_df, it creates a very big dataframe.